# Counting Distinct values from Sql Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Following is a view of my table...

[image]

I am getting a hard time in getting desired result from a query.

My requirement looks like below image

[image]

It should be conditioned as follows --
1)Within start date and end date.

2)No as Pending .

3)Yes as Completed.

4)No+Yes as Total.

5)Based On only one survey Type.

This is what i have tried and got result for above mentioned 1 to 4 condition , but how to impliment 5 condition ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Userid
  ,CASE 
    WHEN [YES] IS NULL
      THEN 0
    ELSE [YES]
    END AS Completed
  ,CASE 
    WHEN [NO] IS NULL
      THEN 0
    ELSE [NO]
    END AS Pending
  ,(
    CASE 
      WHEN [YES] IS NULL
        THEN 0
      ELSE [YES]
      END + CASE 
      WHEN [NO] IS NULL
        THEN 0
      ELSE [NO]
      END
    ) AS Total
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Userid
    ,SurveyStatus
    ,COUNT(ParcelId) AS cnt
  FROM ParcelAllocationsurvivor
  WHERE DateAllocated >= '2013-08-01'
    AND DateAllocated <= '2013-08-07'
  GROUP BY Userid
    ,SurveyStatus
  ) AS p
PIVOT(max(cnt) FOR surveystatus IN ([YES],[NO])) AS pvt
ORDER BY Userid
```

Can anybody help me out in it.

thanks in advance////

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you expect? Do you want the results to only include a survey type or to be grouped by survey type?

Comment: output is same what your are seeing in my requirement image , i need to impliment a where clause like 'Surveytype' = 1

Answer (score 0):

You would add a `where` clause into the subquery:

```
SELECT Userid, (case when [YES] is null then 0 else [YES] end) as Completed,
       (case when [NO] is null then 0 else [NO] end) as Pending,
       (case when [YES] is null then 0 else [YES] end +
        case when [NO] is null then 0 else [NO] end
       ) as Total
FROM (SELECT Userid, SurveyStatus, COUNT(ParcelId) as cnt 
      FROM ParcelAllocationsurvivor
      WHERE DateAllocated >= '2013-08-01' and DateAllocated <='2013-08-07' and
            SurveyType = 'Survey1'
      group by Userid, SurveyStatus
     ) AS p
PIVOT(max(cnt) FOR surveystatus IN([YES],[NO])) AS pvt order by Userid;
```

By the way, the `select distinct` are redundant.  You do not need them for this query.

Comment: No , not working correctly, says total = 1 , pending = 1 , but data is lot bigger , kind of total is 40

Comment: @NewBee . . . Are you sure the inner subquery is returning what you want?  Perhaps the date arithmetic is not doing what you expect.